# Refresh a partial after submiting form_for with remote: true

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a form in a side bar, and when the form submits, I need to refresh only that particular partial from the side bar, not the entire page. The partial has a div id = "class-id" on it.

partial.html.haml

```
- if class
 // display some stuff
- else
  = form_for [Class.new], remote: true do |f| 
    .field
      = f.label :description
      = f.text_field :description      
    .actions
      = f.submit
```

I need to reload this partial after the submit is finished, so that the first if will be accessed.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a view file as your action name, for example. - suppose your action name is `create` in `user controller`  then in your `view/users` folder create a file `create.js.erb` and write below code in that file.

#### For jquery

```
$('class or id name').html("<%= escape_javascript render(:partial => 'whatever your your partial') %>")
```

#### For prototype

```
page.replace_html "class or id name", :partial => "whatever your partial to update"
```